# Why is my query module marked as read only in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I run Memgraph Platform 2.0.11. On my laptop I've created a new query module and I've copied it to the docker:

```
$ docker cp test_module.py prem3:/usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules/test_module.py
Successfully copied 2.56kB to prem3:/usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules/test_module.py
```

When I want to edit it I can see that it is "Read only".

If I copy the code and add Query module from Memgraph Lab then there is no "Read only" mark. Why can't I edit the file that I've copied to Docker?

[image: Read only]